# How do I embed a 3rd party framework inside a framework target in Xcode

Tags: ios8, frameworks, xcode7

I have created a framework target (BourbonKit) inside of my iOS project. BourbonKit needs to include a 3rd party framework. I'm able to add the 3rd party framework to that target and setup the framework search path correctly, but when I try to import the 3rd party framework inside one of BourbonKit's classes I'll get a compile error stating that the 3rd party framework header can't be found.

I know Apple discourages creating umbrella frameworks, but I don't see an alternative in my case and I'm trying to stay away from using CocoaPods and Carthage.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding the 3rd party framework as a linked library to my framework AND then added it's headers to the "project scope" (see attached image)

[image]

I then set the framework search path to the directory where the framework is located. Xcode 6 would automatically set this for you, but in 7b3 you have to set it manually.

Now I'm able to import the 3rd party framework anywhere in my public/private classes that I want to.